# Activate method not working with txt file opened in Excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I need to convert a .txt file into .xlsx format. I have written below code (with the help of macro recorder) to accomplish the same.

Code works fine when i run it in the workbook **(text file open in excel)**. 
But when I try to run it from another Workbook it is not treating it (text file open in excel) as active workbook. Even though I have open it with this line
`objExcel.Workbooks.Open "J:\My Folder\text file name.txt"`. Also tried to activate it with activate method: `Workbooks("text file name.txt").Sheets(1).Select`.

Please help to diagnose the issue and resolve it.

```
Sub txt3()

  Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.Workbooks.Open "J:\My Folder\text file name.txt"


Workbooks("text file name.txt").Sheets(1).Select
MsgBox objExcel.Workbooks.Name ' this line display name of the workbook from which module is running 
ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Select

    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlNone, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon _
        :=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="|", _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array _
        (6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Set worksheet as variable, you will not need select:

```
Dim wsTxt As Worksheet
Set wsTxt = Workbooks.Open("c:\Users\u195567\important\myscript.txt").Worksheets(1)


wsTxt.Range("A1").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlNone, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon _
    :=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="|", _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array _
    (6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Comment: Tried your version but it did nothing, I think it only selcted cell A1 so didi a change and changed this: `wsTxt.Range("A1")` with this : `wstxt.Range("A:A").Select` and `Selection.TextToColumns.` It worked.... Thanks a lot for your fix.

Answer (score 0):

If everything else works, then try to refer to the correct workbook, when doing the selection:

```
Sub txt3()
        Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        objExcel.Visible = True
        objExcel.Workbooks.Open "J:\My Folder\text file name.txt"

        With Workbooks("text file name.txt")
            .Range("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=.Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                TextQualifier:=xlNone, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon _
                :=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="|", _
                FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), _
                Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1)), _
                TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        End With    
    End Sub
```

The `.Range("A:A")` and `.Range("A1")` is what makes the difference. Otherwise, it is taking the ActiveSheet of the current workbook. `Select` and `Activate` have no power there.

Answer (score 0):

as already told you by other guys around here, you must properly reference the correct workbook and worksheet without using `Select`/`Selection`/`Activate`/`ActiveXXX` pattern

moreover if you're running the macro from within an Excel session then you don't need to create a separate Excel session to process the text file

so, if your `TextToColumns()` parameters call are correctly set, then you can code as follows:

```
Sub txt3()
    With Workbooks.Open("J:\My Folder\text file name.txt").Sheets(1)
        .Range("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=.Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlNone, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon _
            :=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="|", _
            FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array _
            (6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    End With
End Sub
```